# Compilation failure when inner class uses outer class template parameter but only when using `ostream`

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I run into a compiler error when an inner class uses the template parameter of the outer class, and I instantiate an output stream operator on the outer class on the member of the inner type.

I have spent a good bit of time trying to resolve this problem.  I believe the following sources come close but I still do not understand *why* I am getting a compilation failure.

- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71dw8xzh.aspx

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        Inner(const T& val = T());
        T data_;
    }; // end class Inner

    Outer();

    void AddInnerChildToOuter(const T& data);
    std::vector<typename Outer<T>::Inner> innerChildren_;
}; // end class Outer


// Inner constructor
template <typename T>
Outer<T>::Inner::Inner(const T& val) : data_(val)
{
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, // Line 27
                         const typename Outer<T>::Inner& gn)
{
    strm << gn.data_ << std::endl;
    return strm;
}

// Outer constructor
template <typename T>
Outer<T>::Outer()
{
}

template <typename T>
void Outer<T>::AddInnerChildToOuter(const T& data)
{
    typename Outer<T>::Inner node(data);
    innerChildren_.push_back(node);
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Outer<T>& g)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g.innerChildren_.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << g.innerChildren_[i] << std::endl; // Line 51
    return strm;
}

int main()
{
    Outer<int> g;
    g.AddInnerChildToOuter(3);
    g.AddInnerChildToOuter(5);
    std::cout << g << std::endl; // Line 60
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error for the `ostream operator <<` on the outer that calls the corresponding output stream operator for the inner.  I am not posting the entire litany of the compiler's error messages; just what I consider to be relevant.

```
$ g++ -Wall -W -Wextra -pedantic -ansi OuterInnerArgh.cpp 
OuterInnerArgh.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Outer<T>&) [with T = int; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:60:18:   required from here
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:51:19: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const Outer<int>::Inner’)
         std::cout << g.innerChildren_[i] << std::endl;
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(snipped compiler's attempts at various `ostream` overloads; more compiler error messages below)

```
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:27:15: note: candidate: template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const typename Outer<T>::Inner&)
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm,
               ^~~~~~~~
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:27:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:51:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
         std::cout << g.innerChildren_[i] << std::endl;
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:48:15: note: candidate: template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Outer<T>&)
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Outer<T>& g)
               ^~~~~~~~
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:48:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
OuterInnerArgh.cpp:51:19: note:   ‘const Outer<int>::Inner’ is not derived from ‘const Outer<T>’
         std::cout << g.innerChildren_[i] << std::endl;
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(snipped rest of compiler errors)

Please let me know why I encounter a compiler error -

- Even though I have an `ostream operator <<` for `typename Outer<T>::Inner&`
- Even when I have "sprinkled" the `typename` "magic-dust" wherever relevant
- Only for the outer `ostream` operator, not for the constructors or the inner `ostream` operator (the latter probably not instantiated at all?)

Why does the compiler say `‘const Outer<int>::Inner’ is not derived from ‘const Outer<T>’`?  (Yes, there is no inheritance, but the inner type definition is nested within the outer)

Comment: I already acknowledged (see very last line in my question) that there is no inheritance.

Comment: Yes, but declaring one class inside another does not make it derived from anything.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but it seems I need to clarify what I am saying:  What I am asking is, _Why does the compiler assume_ `Outer<int>::Inner` means `Inner` is *derived* from `Outer<int>`?  Why can't it be a type defined in `Outer<int>` -- as is the case here?

Comment: I see. It doesn’t assume that — the overload for Outer is one of the available candidates, and the compiler tells you why it can’t be used. Template error messages are no fun, even if they’re better than they used to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got compile error because [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) causes template argument deduction failing.

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 1. The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id:

For example, if you specify the template argument explicitly (in ugly style) it would compile. In the `operator<<` for `Outer`:

```
operator<< <T> (strm, g.innerChildren_[i]);
//         ^^^
```

You can make the `operator<<` non-template (to bypass the type deduction trouble), then you have to define it inside the class definition as `friend`. e.g.

```
struct Inner
{
    Inner(const T& val = T());
    T data_;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm,
                                    const Inner& gn)
    {
        strm << gn.data_ << std::endl;
        return strm;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vC7R80EArBbmRu5y)

Comment: Appreciate the link regarding non-deduced context.  Also thank you very much for two different ways to resolve the issue.  Could you elaborate where the confusion reg. the `std::ostream` overload is for my code (just like the link explained with `good` and `bad` examples for `identity`)?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Sorry I can't get your question exactly. What's your specific confusion?

Comment: _Why_ does the compiler not see the << defined in line 27?  _How_ does your suggested code changes help the compiler in resolving the argument deduction troubles?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Compiler does see it, i.e. it's found by name lookup. But the template parameter `T` can't be deduced from function parameter, then calling fails. For the 1st solution, we specify template argument explicitly to bypass deduction. For the 2nd solution we make `operator<<` a non-template operator, then no template argument deduction is required.

Comment: Thank you very much @songyuanyao.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this

```
std::cout << g.innerChildren_[i] << std::endl; // Line 51
```

to be

```
std::cout << g.innerChildren_[i].data_ << std::endl; // Line 51
```

Because you are trying to use the operator `<<` where it is not defined

If you depend on the defined operator in line (27), modify line (50) to call it properly, as follows

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < g.innerChildren_.size(); ++i)
{
    operator<< <T>(strm, g.innerChildren_[i]);
    strm << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  While it resolves the problem, but does not explain the issue.  There is an `operator <<` defined (line 27).

Comment: Thank you for the update/edit.  I'm still unable to understand _why_ the compiler is unable to determine this (and _how_ the suggested code change then tells the compiler what overload definition to choose).